# UIButton not clickable after UITableView scrolled

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableView which is populated with some cells.  I have created a UIButton using the following snippet, it is placed next to one of the section headers.

```
UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[addButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
addButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
addButton.frame = CGRectMake(270, 150, 29, 29);
```

The button is placed and works correctly.  However, after the view is scrolled (even slightly - like 1 pixel), the button works once and then ceases to respond.  When it fails to respond the action for when it is clicked is not triggered and the button doesn't give the 'depressed' shadow.  The rest of the application runs as normal and it does not crash.

This seems odd because after I scroll the button is clickable once more before it stops working.  The button is used to insert rows into the table, so after it is pressed there is an extra row, possibly this is breaking the bounds or something?

Button pressed function:

```
- (void)addButtonPressed {
    self.addClientTable.editing = YES;

    // First figure out how many sections there are
    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.addClientTable] - 1;

    // Then grab the number of rows in the last section
    NSInteger lastRowIndex = [self.addClientTable numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex];

    [self.addClientTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

    self.addClientTable.editing = NO;
}
```

Where `addClientTable` is the UITableView.

What could cause a UIButton to stop responding to clicks and where in my scenario would this be caused by?

Comment: addClientTable is your tableview, right?

Answer (score 3):

I am almost sure that your problem is that your button is out of it superview, and you are not using the clip subviews option in your view that contains the button, or in one of it superviews.

Set to true all the views property clip subviews and see if it appears your button. (We expect that the button disappear)

If you provide more code I can try to help you to solve this problem.

-

Reading again your question, another probable problem to it is that you have one view in front of your button. You can test it changing the background of your view, or something like that.

Comment: I've turned on Clip Subviews and ClipToBound for the view that contains the button and nothing has changed.  The button still displays and still won't work.  There doesn't seem to be a view in front of it either.

Comment: @Ollie Can you provide more code or maybe a demo so I can see the problem? I am pretty sure that is a problem with you button bounds or a problem with your view hierarchy. Because I do not believe that you are disabling the interaction with the button.

Comment: @ggrana Sorry to sidetrack this, but I've got a similar problem but the other way around: the button is not clickable until the user scrolls. When I turn on 'clip subviews' for the header I notice that the non-clickable part is clipped out until I scroll. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: @benwad you superview is too small, the area that you want to click is outside it bounds, you need to define a bigger frame size, you need to see the button you want to use even when clip subviews is on.

Comment: @ggrana that's the solution! It turns out that the header view is laid out dynamically as a result of an asynchronous web request, but the bounds of the wrapper view for the header were not recalculated when the request came back. So, while the UI elements were all visible (when clip subviews was off) they were outside the wrapper.

Comment: brilliant, this answer saved my day!